# How should I import modules local to a project?

Tags: python

Following [this file structure](http://as.ynchrono.us/2007/12/filesystem-structure-of-python-project_21.html), my project looks as follows (simplified):

```
Project/
|-- project/
    |-- test/
        |-- test_foo.py
    |-- foo.py
```

Using best practices, how should I import `foo` from within `test_foo.py`? I'm aware of relative imports, but [PEP 8 discourages them](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In unit tests, at least those for external interfaces, prefer absolute imports. Tests should look as much like client code as possible, and they should break when things get moved around, when an `__init__.py` doesn't properly re-export from modules, etc.

Answer (score 0):

From tests, I always use `from .. import foo`, because it's the simplest, makes the package easiest to refactor, and isn't going to break, because I always keep my tests in a `tests/` sub-package.

The relative imports the first half of PEP8 discusses are implicit relative imports: for example, from `foo.py`: `import test.test_foo`. These *are* bad, and there's *never* a reason to use them.

Otherwise, the only option is `from project import foo`.